# MSSql Database randomly not answering

Tags: windows-7, database, 32-bit, ms-sql

We have a 32 Bit production machine that has MS SQL 2014 installed. 32 Bit is forced by twincat 2 running on it, (not compatible with 64 bit), thus the available ram is limited.

Randomly, about twice a month, the database does not answer to the programs and the queries go in timeout. (exception 0x80131904)

There seems to be no apparent reason for this, and we cannot figure out what could be causing it. Being it a production machine, there are no particular events, no users playing on it, the system is just there with an application writing to the database about once a minute. It is also a very low load application and the load on the pc is minimal.

What I am asking for, is sugestions on where to look to identify the problem. Is there a log or some comands that I can execute to get at least some hints on what is causing it?

Comment: 1) Could the database be installed on a separate computer? 2) I assume updating to TwinCAT 3 is not possible. 3) You should be able to copy the SQL Server error logs from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance name>\MSSQL\Log" - they are named "ERRORLOG", "ERRORLOG.1", "ERRORLOG.2" etc., and read them on another machine (they are plain text files).

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for your answer! 1) nope, it cannot be installed on a separate computer. 2) no, also not possible for this specific machine. 3) there is nothing inside the errorlog beside a line like this every about 10 minutes: `2021-05-10 11:28:44.59 spid53      Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'.`

Comment: I'm wondering why you mentioned the RAM - if SQL Server is taking an unreasonable amount, you can try [How do I limit MS SQL Server memory usage?](https://serverfault.com/q/387682/109573)

Comment: @andrew morton thank you that is already set up to 1 gig..

Comment: I'd suggest restarting the machine once a week, but that wouldn't be identifying the problem. Does the PC have plenty of free disk space? How long is the timeout - can it be increased? Is the screensaver disabled? Is SQL Server fully updated? [The Most Recent Updates for Microsoft SQL Server](https://sqlserverupdates.com/) Did you check the Windows event logs for just before the timeout?

Comment: @AndrewMorton free space is 78 gigs out of 111... The timeout is 600 seconds...In the event manager there is nothing with the same time.. I dont know the update status of the machine, since updates are disabled. but given that the machine is 2 years old and sql 2014 is rather old, it should be up to date, or at least almost up to date.

Comment: Could you check the database auto-close setting? [How to Disable Auto Close in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-close-enabled/)

Comment: @AndrewMorton it was enabled. its set to false now. You think that this could be the cause even if the software has written 1 minute prior?

Comment: It *might* fix it, but of course it will take some time to find out. It seems a bit strange that a 600 second timeout would be insufficient for it to wake up - I wonder what happened to other queries in that time?